# log de errores en bash

Tags: bash, script, curl

quisiera saber como puedo crear un log o tener control de los datos que se actualizan o no en este script de bash leo un csv y envío los datos con CURL y el .sh funciona correctamente ahora quisiera  generar un log de errores o tener un mensaje que me indique cuales campos fueron actualizados

```
while IFS=, read  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7 col8
do
        echo "_________________________________"
        echo "Nombre del Sitio de Proveedor ->[${col1}]"
        echo "NIT del proveedor -> [${col2}]"
        echo "Email de notificación  -> [${col3}]"
        echo "Grupo de contenido -> [${col4}]"
        echo "CODE   -> [${col5}]"
        echo "COD S1ESA  -> [${col6}]"
        echo "CODE NUEVO  -> [${col7}]"
        echo "ACTIVO  -> [${col8}]"

        url="https://example.com/api/suppliers?number=${col2}"
        echo "COnsultando "$url
        curl -g  -H "Accept: application/xml" -H "X-COUPA-API-KEY:3bce24adc7ef16199c10c6dec2d1980a612f4bb3" -H "X-HTTP-Method-Override: GET" $url >nit.xml
        Supplier_id=$(cat nit.xml | xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//supplier" -v "id")
        echo $Supplier_id

        url="https://example.com/api/suppliers/"$Supplier_id"/supplier_sites?code=${col5}"
        echo $url
        curl -g  -H "Accept: application/xml" -H "X-API-KEY:3bce24adc7ef16199c10c6dec2d1980a60000012" -H "X-HTTP-Method-Override: GET" $url >nit1.xml
        supplier_site_id=$(cat nit1.xml | xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//supplier-site"  -v "id" )
        echo "id_site" $supplier_site_id

        IFS='-' read -ra contentG <<< "${col4}"
        for i in "${contentG[@]}"; do
        echo "$i"
      "<supplier-site><content-groups><content-group><name>${col4}</name></content-group>/<content-groups></supplier-site>"
done


        url_put="https://example.com/api/suppliers/"$Supplier_id"/supplier_sites/"$supplier_site_id
        curl -g -X PUT -d "<supplier-site><content-groups><content-group><name>$i</name></content-group></content-groups><name>${col1}</name><po-email>${col3}</po-emai$        echo  "<supplier-site><content-groups><content-group><name>${col4}</content-groups>/<content-group></name><name>${col1}</name><po-email>${col3}</po-email><acti$
done < campos.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes filtrar por varias cosas, por ejemplo, por algún valor valor o mensaje que te devuelva el response o usando el parámetro `-i` de curl, que incluye, al inicio del response, la información del header de http.

El resultado de esa consulta, si falla el servicio, podría darte algo por el estilo:

```
$ curl -i --url $url -H etc -s
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
...
```

Y podrías filtrar según el status code o algún header o mensaje por ahí. O también podrías usar algo como el modo verboso de curl.

```
$ curl -v etc etc
...
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
...
```

Y sigues una dinámica semejante de filtrar según la respuesta.

Puedes hacer una función que filtre por alguno de esos valores que te mencioné y, según ese filtro, guardar las coincidencias en archivos diferentes.

Algo por este estilo.

```
create_log() {
    declare id_suplier_code="$1"  # O algún parámetro por lo que lo identifiques.
    declare response="$2"
    ERROR_LOG_FILE="error.log"
    SUCCESS_LOG_FILE="success.log"

    status_code="$(awk '$1=="HTTP/1.1"{$1="";print $0}' <<< "$response")"       

    if [[ $(egrep -q "200 OK" <<< "$status_code") ]]
    then
        echo "[SUCCESS]:$id_suplier_code" >> "$SUCCESS_LOG_FILE"
    else
        echo "[ERROR]:$id_suplier_code:$status_code" >> "$ERROR_LOG_FILE" 
    fi
}
```

Esa función la usarías pasándole como parámetros el id de lo que quieras identificar y el response de la petición de curl que hiciste previamente.

Comment: Muchas gracias
Por tu respuesta quisiera saber si ese mismo script me serviría para mostrar o guardar los errores que me genere la carga de un dato es decir el PUT por ejemplo un campo del csv venga vació donde me guardaría el error de que ese campo no se actualizo Muchas gracias

Comment: @JHABIER Para saber ese tipo de cosas específicas, tendrías que ponerte de acuerdo con el creador de ese servicio para que él te valide lo que se puede ingresar, lo que no y que, con base en eso, te devuelva los mensajes de respuesta y códigos de estado correspondientes. Una vez que tengas esa convención, puedes filtrar sobre respuesta o código de estado con cURL, como lo mostré.

Comment: Por ejemplo, le pides al desarrollador de esa API que te devuelva un estado 40x (cuatrocientos y algo) y un mensaje de error que diga algo como: "Campo 1 inválido" o "Campo 1 vacío" y filtras sobre ese código de estado y mensaje (con egrep) y luego lo insertas en los logs, todo eso sería semejante a la función que sugerí, claro, con otras condiciones (if-else) más.